# facebook plugin - share and like

Tags: facebook, button, share, facebook-like

I have a web page with photo gallery. At the moment there are 3500+ photos uploaded, so each photo (post) has he's unique link. The facebook comment box and like + send buttons are working, I successfully implemented the META elements (title, description and thumbnail), but I have some trouble or misunderstands.

When somebody like's the photo, why the post isn't showed on he's news feed? It's only showed on he's own wall. I want something like, when you share a video on yo*tube, the video immediately are showed on you're wall and news feed, so everybody can see the shared video.

I want to make some extra visits, but with this method, I only get if somebody visits others wall.

Is there any difference between like and share buttons? If is, where can I find share button plugin?

Here is my code:

```
<fb:like href='http://www.example.com/index.php?id=XX' send='true' width='450' show_faces='false'></fb:like>
```

It's XFBML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When someone clicks your Like Button, a News Story should also show up in the News Feeds of some of their friends, but this will be inconsistent and based on Facebook's [Edge Rank Algorithm](http://www.insidefacebook.com/2011/12/27/edgerank-and-graph-rank-defined/).

Facebook no longer officially supports the Share Button, but for now you can still implement it, either with JavaScript:

```
<a name="fb_share" type="button" share_url="http://www.yourdomain.com">Share</a> 
<script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

Or by linking to the Sharer.php app:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yourdomain.com" target="_blank">Share</a>
```